# How to recover the files in KNOX mode after I have rooted the device ?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-knox

Samung S4, Android 4.4.4
I rooted my device, and now can't access the files in KNOX mode. 
Should i  unroot it or what ?

Answer (score -1):

Factory Wipe/ Restart

Use the windows program odin from sammobile.com, next flash your factory firmware.

1. Plug device into computer
2. Run Odin
3. Find firmware on http://sammobile.com
4. Download firmware
5. Power off device
6. Power on device while holding power + home button + vol up, then release power button after about 3 seconds
7. You should be in Odin Mode
8. Now follow the directions listed below the firmware download on http://sammobile.com
9. Your phone should reboot and have you guided through a setup process like you just got the device